# HiDPI screen. Changing layout.css.devPixelsPerPx in Firefox does not work for gmail

Tags: firefox, display-resolution, gmail

I'm experiencing a lot of problem with my new laptop with HiDPI screen and Ubuntu 16.04. Maybe the most annoying is related to Mozilla Firefox. I partially solved it by using the hint described [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-get-firefox-looking-right-on-a-high-dpi-display-and-fedora/) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Firefox). Essentially, they say to change the value of the parameter `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` to the desired one.

Anyway, it seems that Firefox ignores this new setting **ONLY** when I use gmail. For example, if I have 4 tabs open, on three sites the graphics is scaled according to the new settings, but when I open the tab containing gmail, it looks very very small (both the site and the Firefox interface itself).

How can I get rid from this problem?